# sequence value for id in ddl2hbm

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

i will use sequence for primary key. I use hibernate tools in eclipse to generate ORMs. i couldn't identify an option to mention sequence for ID in java bean.

like

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "G1")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "G1", sequenceName = "LOG_SEQ")
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}
```

Is there a way to mention it and generate bean class with it?

Answer (score 0):

In the definition below LOG_SEQ is the name of the sequence in the database that that ID should use to generate the values

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "G1", sequenceName = "LOG_SEQ")
```

Have

```
 java.lang.String   sequenceName 
          (Optional) The name of the database sequence object from which to obtain primary key values.
```

At the end you should substitue sequenceName for the one that is in your database schema consider using

schema property of the annotation, take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what i want to know is how the sequence can be mentioned in hibernate.reveng.xml for generating ORMs